# How to change variable in another python file?

Tags: python, file, variables

I have two python files. In this example I have made it really simple, File_A and File_B. In File_A I want to define a variable, and in File_B I want to use this variable to do something.
The code is a bit more complex, but this is the idea:

FileA:

```py
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(window)
entry.pack()
button = tk.Button(window, text="Click me!", command=lambda: on_button_click(entry.get()))
button.pack()

def on_button_click(ip):
    pass
  #changing variable in File_B to 'ip'
  #run File_B

window.mainloop()
```

File_B:

```py
print(value) #value entered in File_A
```

I have tried things in File_B like:

```
From File_A import value
```

But this didn't seem to work for me, or it made the GUI open once more.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: `value` is not defined in File_A, so file_B won't be able to import it when you do  `From File_A import value`. that's the problem, you cannot import a variable that doesn;t exist. Could you also fix the formatting? FileB code does not show properly.

Comment: Where do I need to define value? Because when I do it inside the function File_B cant read the variable.

Comment: that's the point. you are trying to read a variable that does not exist in FileA. Look at the code in FileA, there's nowhere there where you assign that variable a value, so the variable doesn't exist. You cannot import something nonexistent.

Comment: I know. The code above was just to show how I wanted it to work. The problem is even when I do assign a value, File_B doesnt seem to run and use the variable. I'm quite new to this, so I have no idea if I'm giving the variable a value in the "wrong place".

Comment: then you should rewrite your question with code that reproduces your problem. why don;t you put functions in FileB that you can call from File A and pass the desired variable as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the file's code with a function instead, and pass relevant variables using the function parameters.

TestB:

```
def main(ip):
    print(ip)
    
    <rest of code for file TestB>
```

TestA:

```
import TestB

def on_button_click(ip):
    TestB.main(ip)
```

Maybe add more details to your question (what are you trying to do?), there might be a more efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: I want to define a variable inside the function in File_A. After that I want to automatically run File_B.
In this case it's a simple print statement, using the variable defined in File_A.

Comment: @Thomas I edited my answer, maybe this helps? In general you should try and split your code into functions rather than just running the entirety of file B as an import.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. I cannot give you an upvote, but this helped me a lot!